# HttpClient.PostAsync(UrlPath, stream) fails forward posting multipart/form-data stream received in a FileUpload HttpRequest

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, upload, stream, httpclient

Using POSTMAN I can post to http://XXXXXXXazurewebsites.net/api/Blob/UploadDoc with BODY containing form-data that is 2 text fields and a file stream.  In fact, with Postman, I can have the body be empty, and it still posts to the Api endpoint, as I confirmed with a break-point while remote debugging.

And, the code using HttpClient is able to post to the AspnetCore Api endpoint when it is running locally (ie: http://localhost:8888/api/Blob/UploadDoc).

But when the same endpoint code is deployed on Azure, the HttpClient.PostAsync receives 404 while posting to the exact same URL that Postman is able to make a POST request to.

QUESTION: How can this be working on 2 instances of IISExpress running locally, but fail when deployed in Azure?

---

The client code is inside of an [HttpPost] method on a Controller in the Presentation App Svc, and is forwarding the Request Content a a stream to an Api controller running in a different App Svc:

```
            HttpClient localclient = new HttpClient();
            //localclient.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("http://localhost:8888/api/"); //works posting to here
            localclient.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("http://XXXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/");  //404 posting to site on azure!
            HttpContent contentStream = new StreamContent(request.Body);
            await localclient.PostAsync("Blob/UploadDoc", contentStream);
```

I have also tried reading in the stream as a byte[] and creating a HttpContent from the byte[].  But the HttpClient.Post gets a 404 with that as well, ala:

```
  var memstream = new MemoryStream();
  await request.Body.CopyToAsync(memstream);
  memstream.Position = 0;
  var contentba = new ByteArrayContent(memstream.ToArray());
  var response = await localclient.PostAsJsonAsync("Blob/UploadDoc", contentba);
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();  // 404 when posting to site on Azure
```

The Api code is as follows:

```
        [HttpPost("UploadDoc")]
        [DisableFormValueModelBinding]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadBlobAsync()
        { 
        //work with Request  ...
        }
```

And the browser is uploading a file ala:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="https://AAAAAA.azurewebsites.net/api/Blob/UploadDoc" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="AJAXSubmit(this);return false;">
            <input id="submissionId" type="text" name="submissionId" maxlength="25" />
            <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Upload"  />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you deployment to Azure Web Apps? As asp.net core applications running on Azure Web Apps are hosted on IIS. So there is a web.config file required to config your application on IIS.

You may check this file in your root directory of your site on azure, whether it is in the correct configurations.

Here is a sample of a web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebAppEver.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this was caused by not setting the Request.Body Position back to zero, or in some way not building the request properly, which in turn causes the target host to not consider the Post request to match any of it's endpoints.

If I make the request as follows, then it works:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAsync(HttpRequest request, HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
            var requestMethod = request.Method;

            if (!HttpMethods.IsGet(requestMethod) &&
                !HttpMethods.IsHead(requestMethod) &&
                !HttpMethods.IsDelete(requestMethod) &&
                !HttpMethods.IsTrace(requestMethod))
            {
                request.EnableRewind();
                request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var streamContent = new StreamContent(request.Body);
                requestMessage.Content = streamContent;
            }

            foreach (var header in request.Headers)
            {
                if (!requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value.ToArray()))
                {
                    requestMessage.Content?.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value.ToArray());
                }
            }

            var uri = new Uri(Client.BaseAddress, "UploadDoc");
            requestMessage.Headers.Host = uri.Authority;
            requestMessage.RequestUri = uri;
            requestMessage.Method = new HttpMethod(request.Method);
            var response = await Client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

            httpContext.Response.RegisterForDispose(response);
            return new HttpResponseMessageResult(response);
      }
```

```
    public class HttpResponseMessageResult : IActionResult
    {
        private readonly HttpResponseMessage _responseMessage;

        public HttpResponseMessageResult(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
        {
            _responseMessage = responseMessage; // could add throw if null
        }

        public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)_responseMessage.StatusCode;

            foreach (var header in _responseMessage.Headers)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.TryAdd(header.Key, new StringValues(header.Value.ToArray()));
            }
            using (var stream = await _responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(context.HttpContext.Response.Body);
                await context.HttpContext.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```